# Getting a new column with distance to the nearest feature in R

Tags: r, sf

Having two sf data frames (`a` is points and `b` is polygons),
I can get columns from the nearest feature by for instance:

```
c <- st_join(a, b, st_nearest_feature),
```

But how is the best way to get an additional column with the distance as well?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Don't do the join. `st_nearest_feature(a,b)` will get you the index (row number) of the nearest feature in `b` to each feature in `a`.

EG using data `p` and `l` from `?st_nearest_feature` made into `sf` data frame:

```
> (nearest = st_nearest_feature(p,l))
[1] 1 2 2 3
```

Then use `st_distance` to get the element-wise distances between each element of `p` and the corresponding element of `l`:

```
> (dist = st_distance(p, l[nearest,], by_element=TRUE))
[1] 0.10 0.01 0.01 0.10
```

You could use the nearest index to do the join like this:

```
> (pljoin = cbind(p, st_drop_geometry(l)[nearest,]))
Simple feature collection with 4 features and 2 fields
geometry type:  POINT
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 0.1 ymin: -0.1 xmax: 0.1 ymax: 0.9
epsg (SRID):    NA
proj4string:    NA
  id st_drop_geometry.l..nearest...         geometry
1  a                              A POINT (0.1 -0.1)
2  b                              B POINT (0.1 0.11)
3  c                              B POINT (0.1 0.09)
4  d                              C  POINT (0.1 0.9)
```

(Column names are a bit mashed up but maybe you can work with that)

Then add the distance:

```
> pljoin$dist = dist
>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I get a warning when running the cbind: number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 2). And my pljoin is then a list. It works if I take away the st_drop_geometry though, but with an extra shape field. How to avoid this?

Comment: `nearest` should be the same length as rows in `p`, so `l[nearest,]` should be the same number of rows as `p` so the `cbind` should work. Hard to figure out without your data or more details.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `nngeo` package to do that.

In particular, `st_nn(a, b, k = 1, returnDist = T)` returns both the nearest neighbor and distance. More generally, you can find j nearest neighbors with the corresponding distance by setting k = j in the `st_nn` argument.

Comment: This package is really helpful. I was getting very cryptic error messages when I try to use a combination of `sf::st_distance()` and `sf::st_nearest_feature()` to achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the above solutions to be extremely helpful, but very slow on large datasets. Also I found that weird implementations like `st_distance` in `sf` put off newcomers that want to use R for spatial analysis. Anyway, here is my solution that has a lot more code but trust me it's a lot faster than the standard `st_distance` function.

```
#add the coordinates for the points in SF dataframe A and B --------------
a_coord <- st_coordinates(a)
a <- cbind(a, a_coord)

b_coord <- st_coordinates(b)
b <- cbind(b, b_coord)


#get closest feature in B to A -----------------------------------------
A_B <- a %>%
  st_join(b %>%
          select(B_ID, X, Y) %>%
            rename(B_X = X, B_Y = Y), join = st_nearest_feature)



#create a WKT from the coords of A and closest feature in B --------------
A_B$line_wkt <- paste('linestring(',A_B$X,A_B$Y,',',A_B$B_X,A_B$B_Y,')')


#Convert WKT into Geom--------------------------------------
A_B <- A_B %>% 
  st_drop_geometry() %>%
  st_as_sf( wkt = 'line_wkt ', crs= 4326)


#Get the length (distance) of each line ----------------------------------
A_B$length <- as.numeric(st_length(A_B) )


#Join results with original A --------------------------------------------
a <- a %>%
  left_join(A_B %>%
              st_drop_geometry() %>%
              select(A_ID, B_ID, length), by = 'A_ID')
```