# Distance between nearest neighbors R GIS

Tags: r, sf

I am using `nngeo` to identify for each `town` the nearest `city`. Library `nngeo` is available [here](https://michaeldorman.github.io/nngeo/).

I want to also report the distance between each `town` and its nearest `city`.

I wanted to use `gDistance` but am not sure how to properly specify it. Does anyone have an idea?

```
towns$dist<-apply(t(gDistance(towns,cities,byid = TRUE)),MARGIN = 1, FUN = "min")
```

```
install.packages("nngeo")
library(nngeo)

data(towns)
data(cities)

matched = st_join(towns, cities, join = nngeo::st_nn, maxdist = 5000, k = 1, progress = TRUE)
```

Comment: (there's only 6 nearest-neighbours within the range of 5000, is that what you want?)

Comment: Use `st_nn` to get a list of nearest neighbours indexes, then `lapply` and other loops to get the distance via `st_distance` to the cities by indexing using the match vector. But what do you want done when there's no nearest point within the threshold in `st_nn`?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the solution presented in this answer (using the sf package): [Getting a new column with distance to the nearest feature in R](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/349955/getting-a-new-column-with-distance-to-the-nearest-feature-in-r)

I complete as requested in the comment. It is also possible to use such a code. It is slower because it is executed row by row. I assume that `source_geometry` and `target_geometry` are data in the form of sf with geometry column named `geometry`.

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.3, GDAL 3.5.2, PROJ 8.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(tidyverse)

#creating data

target_geometry <- st_sfc(st_point(c(1,0)), st_point(c(2,0)), st_point(c(3,0)), st_point(c(4,0)),
                 st_point(c(5,0)), st_point(c(6,0))) %>% 
  st_as_sf(tibble(name = LETTERS[1:6]))
source_geometry <- st_sfc(st_point(c(2,1)), st_point(c(5,1))) %>% 
  st_as_sf(tibble(name = 1:2))

st_geometry(target_geometry) <- "geometry"
st_geometry(source_geometry) <- "geometry"



source_geometry %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(nearest_id = st_nearest_feature(geometry, target_geometry),
         nearest_name = target_geometry$name[nearest_id],
         nearest_geom = st_geometry(target_geometry$geometry[nearest_id]),
         distance = st_distance(geometry, nearest_geom)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-nearest_geom)
#> Simple feature collection with 2 features and 4 fields
#> Geometry type: POINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 2 ymin: 1 xmax: 5 ymax: 1
#> CRS:           NA
#> # A tibble: 2 × 5
#>    name geometry nearest_id nearest_name distance[,1]
#>   <int>  <POINT>      <int> <chr>               <dbl>
#> 1     1    (2 1)          2 B                       1
#> 2     2    (5 1)          5 E                       1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Posting a link to another answer with no code or explanation from you is not an appropriate way to answer as indicated at this link: https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: I supplemented the answer with another code that I was using for this purpose. I am sorry that your previous answer did not comply with the rules.

Comment: Did you mean to type "... my previous answer"? I did not give an answer. I was commenting on yours. No apologies are necessary. My comment was intended to be constructive, not punitive.

Comment: Yes, of course it was about my earlier answer. Sorry. Unfortunately, I can't edit a comment anymore.

Comment: No problem at all. :)